# SWT - Showing a busy Cursor

Tags: java, swt, mouse-cursor

I am trying to change the cursor when I start a operation.  I want the cursor showing busy until the operation is finished.  I have a separate class for the operationListener.
I am not sure how to assign the cursor?

Call from AplotBaseDialog class

```
listOp.addOperationListener(new MyOperationListener(this) {
    etc....
}
```

Separate Class

```
 public abstract class MyOperationListener implements InterfaceAIFOperationListener {
   Cursor busyCursor = null;
   AplotBaseDialog w = null;

  public MyOperationListener(AplotBaseDialog win) {

  **Should this not be getCurrent?**
    busyCursor = new Cursor(Display.getCurrent(), SWT.CURSOR_WAIT);

    w = win;
  } // end constructor

  public void startOperation(String startMessage) {
     ** should this be getting a Shell form the AplotBaseDialog? **
     w.???.setCursor(busyCursor);

  } // end startOperation()

  public void endOperation() {
     try {
        endOperationImpl();
     }
     finally {
        w.???.setCursor(null);
     }
  } // end endOperation()

  abstract protected void endOperationImpl();
 } // end class MyOperationListener
```

**EDIT**

```
  plotButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
         public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            BusyIndicator.showWhile(Display.getDefault(), new Runnable(){
               public void run(){
                  startPrinterListOperation(); 
               }
             });
         }
   });
```

**EDIT**

```
 private void startPrinterListOperation() {

  listOp = new AplotPrinterListOperation(appReg.getString("aplot.message.GETPRINTERLIST"), session);
  listOp.addOperationListener(new MyOperationListener(this) {
     public void endOperationImpl() {
        try {
           printers.clear();
           printers.addAll((ArrayList<PrinterProfile>) listOp.getPrinters());
           Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {

                 showAplotPlotterDialog();
              }
           });
        }
        finally {

           listOp.removeOperationListener(this);
           listOp = null;
        }
     }
  });
  session.queueOperation(listOp);


 } // end startPrinterListOperation()
```

Comment: It is probably better to use `Display.getSystemCursor(int)` instead of creating cursor objects yourself since you need to dispose them yourself otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
private static boolean wait = false;

private static Cursor cursor = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("Change cursor");

    button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0) {
            wait = !wait;

            if(cursor != null)
                cursor.dispose();

            cursor = wait ? new Cursor(display, SWT.CURSOR_WAIT) : new Cursor(display, SWT.CURSOR_ARROW);

            shell.setCursor(cursor);
        }
    });


    shell.setSize(200,200);
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();

    if(cursor != null)
        cursor.dispose();
}
```

Just set the cursor of your containing shell via [`setCursor(Display, int)`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Control.html#setCursor%28org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Cursor%29).

If you don't want to change the cursor for the whole shell, use a `Composite` or `Control` of your choice.

---

Remember that you have to `dispose()` each `Cursor` instance you create yourself.

Comment: I basically just added the above lines to my operation method as it started then right before the dialog is opened and it seems to work.  I really wish I could have figured out how to made it work in the abstract operation class.  But this seems to have the same effect. - Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You could use

```
    BusyIndicator.showWhile(Display.getDefault(), new Runnable(){

    public void run(){
       //your code
    }
    });
```

Comment: I tried putting that in my button action, but it did not do anything. Please See Above

Comment: could you post what you are doing in startPrinterListOperation()? Do you see any exception?

Comment: So you are opening a dialog in async thread after your operation is done. BusyIndicator shows a busy cursor until the runnable is completed. I am not sure how ***Operation class works in your case. You could actually put the **Operation code that you are doing in Runnable.run() method and once the that is done, open up the dialog in async thread as you were doing above.